# What happens to columns with IMAGE datatype after SQL-Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table which contains a column with the IMAGE datatype. This datatype will be removed in future versions of MS SQL Server. What happens to this column and the data stored in it, if I don't change it to another datatype before updating the server?

Will it be removed or is it still accessible?

Comment: The image type has been deprecated since SQL 2005. Once it is actually removed from the product, I would expect its use to block upgrades if you don't change it to varbinary(MAX).

Comment: The `image` data type (last I checked) was still available in SQL Server 2019, however, I still suggest you change your datatype; the fact that it will be removed (at some point) is just one reason.

Comment: I know that changing the datatype is the best option, but I can't make sure that the datatype is changed in all databases before they will be updated to newer server version. So it would be good to know what happens in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft clearly indicated that `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed from future SQL versions. You should try to change these datatypes to  `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)`.

In one environment I faced problem while maintenance jobs were running and failed. If these columns are part of Indexes then we can not rebuild online. Only offline operation is supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to this column and the data stored in it, if I don't change it to another datatype before updating the server?

As you see, it was not removed in SQL Server 2019 but the you can ask the same question about the next version and so on until it will be removed, so here is my 2 cents :-)

(1) IMAGE data type is a binary data type and you can simply take the raw data as it is and store it in VARBINARY data type. There are differences between these types regarding the use of the data and the fact that IMAGE always stored as LOB data while VARBINARY can be stored as In-row data (which is advantage) and there are a few bytes different related to metadata but the stored data of the file itself is the same (you can confirm this using DBCC PAGE command).

Therefore, my guess (without any internal information but a pure guess) is that the step to remove IMAGE will be (or should be) by using IMAGE name as a synonym to VARBINARY exactly like ROWVERSION and TIMESTAMP are synonyms for the same data type. Using this approach Microsoft do not need to actually do a lot, and developers will be able to support old applications simpler.

(2) You can directly explicitly CONVERT IMAGE to VARBINARY and vice versa

In any case, in my opinion you should NOT use IMAGE data type and as sooner as you make the change is better.